# Access server using IP on another interface

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I am using Windows Server 2012 instead of a router for my home network. Currently I am using RRAS and computers from local network can access Internet correctly.

Here is a map of the current setup:

```
[PC1] ---|
         |---- (lan ip)[Server](wan ip)--> internet
[PC2] ---|
```

I have applications running on Server, such as IIS and others. All can be accessed from internet using `wan ip` and from lan using `lan ip`. I have a domain, lets say its `my-domain.com`, which is resolved to my `wan ip`.

What I want is to enable my LAN computers to be able to connect to services on my server using the very same address as internet users: eg `http://my-domain.com/`. However this does not work for my lan computers.

What I understand is that I need to set up some kind of loopback route in a way that packets comming to LAN interface get routed to WAN interface. But I haven't found how to achieve this (in fact, I don't know WHAT to search for).

Feel free to ask for additional informations and I will try to update the question.

Comment: What are your DNS settings? If you want this change across all services, make the public IP resolve for the my-domain.com server.

Comment: @Ryan `my-domain.com` is, of course, resolved to my `wan ip` address. As I stated in the question, external users CAN use both WAN ip and domain. LAN users can use ONLY the LAN ip. My goal is to be able to use WAN ip AND domain from LAN side.

Comment: OK I think I understand your question better now. It's just that you can't reach the public IP successfully from the LAN. What happens when you try to tracert to the public IP from the LAN?

Comment: @Ryan The request times out in the first hop. The firewall is not blocking ICMP packets as pinging lan ip, as well as pinging wan ip from outside is working.

Comment: You can add your domain to a split DNS function if using as DNS for the domain. Local clients get internal ip external resolve public ip.  Or if the server is a forwarding DNS you can set up domain alias to the internal ip so lan clients resolve the internal ip

Comment: But I think you are looking for is NAT Reflection. I have only set it up on pfSense but I think you can find more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a little searching on the web and found that NAT reflection that would be needed is not supported in windows server.

Is the windows server just acting as the router or is it doing many more functions ie. mail, AD?

You can add your domain to a split DNS function if using as DNS for the domain. Local clients get internal ip external resolve public ip. Or if the server is a forwarding DNS you can set up domain alias to the internal ip so lan clients resolve the internal ip

If its just your router. I would suggest switching to a OS specifically for routing ie. pfSense. This would reduce the overhead of running windows server as router.
Once installed the setting is under System > Advanced > Firewall / NAT then enable pure NAT
[image: Pure nat]

Comment: Thanx for your effort in researching this. I can't believe that such product don't offer functionality as a 20$ router... Split DNS would work for the exact situation I described in question but it wouldn't work if I forwarded a port to LAN computer and wanted to access it using external address (router would forward internal packets to internal interface). I will accept in few days, if nobody comes with better solution.

Comment: I agree that if your going to have routing capabilities that should include features that other systems provide by default. But why think that... its microsoft.